# Python List content stripping

Tags: python, pandas, list

So, I have a list having string such as

```
matches=['A vs B','C vs D','E vs F','G vs H']
```

I want to get strip the list contents in such a way that I get two more lists of

```
t1=[A,C,E,G]
t2=[B,D,F,H]
```

I've tried strip function as

```
t1=[i.strip("vs")[0] for i in matches]
t2=[i.strip("vs")[-1] for i in matches]
```

But I'm not getting the desirable results. Can someone guide me trough it. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use :

```
t1, t2 = map(list, zip(*[m.split(" vs ") for m in matches]))
```

And since you have a [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) tag, here is any approach with [`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and the [`Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/series.html) *constructor* :

```
t1, t2 = (
            pd.Series(matches)
                .str.split(" vs ", expand=True)
                .values
                .T.tolist()
          )
```

Output :

```
print(t1)
#['A', 'C', 'E', 'G']
print(t2)
#['B', 'D', 'F', 'H']
```

Comment: Great, both of the approaches are working I actually tried map but was getting an error due to syntax but really fascinated by the use of series here. Didn't even thought that I could get the result that way. Thanks

Comment: That's weird how the pure python approach throws an error, working fine with me and you're welcome ;)

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the *matches* list. Split each element on whitespace. Populate your lists.

```
matches=['A vs B','C vs D','E vs F','G vs H']

t1 = []
t2 = []

for match in matches:
    a, _, b = match.split()
    t1.append(a)
    t2.append(b)

print(t1)
print(t2)
```

**Output:**

```
['A', 'C', 'E', 'G']
['B', 'D', 'F', 'H']
```

Comment: Thanks @Pingu but actually I'm getting an error with this approach as "string getting too long" as I also have other data in the string.

Comment: @Aditya You'll need a different approach then. This answer was based on your question. Very few contributors in stack**overflow** are psychic